# Java SQL insert where 2 same values dont already exist

Tags: java, mysql

In my java application, I'm trying to insert a "player round" into my database where the same player can't be at the same "holeNumber" a second time.

My PlayerRound table

[image]

Currently, I have this and the last line is just pseudo code to show what I'm trying to do.

```
"insert into PlayerRound(playerID, roundID, holeNumber, holeScore) "
    + "select (select playerID from Player where playerID = ?),"
    + "(select roundID from Round where roundID = ?),"
    + "(select holeID from HoleDetails where holeID = ?),? "
    + "WHERE playerID and holeNumber dont already exist in the table"; //correction in sql?
```

The selects are just checking to checking the foreign keys from the tables.

The part I can't understand how to do is the last line. I don't know where the "WHERE" statement should go and how it should check if the current table already has the same playerID in that same holeNumber as previously inserted.

Current insert statement:

```
"insert into PlayerRound(playerID, roundID, holeNumber, holeScore) "
    + "select (select playerID from Player where playerID = ?),"
    + "(select roundID from Round where roundID = ?),"
    + "(select holeID from HoleDetails where holeID = ?), ?"
```

[image]

```
try {
        PreparedStatement pdt = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
        pdt.setString(1, playerID);
        pdt.setString(2, roundID);
        pdt.setString(3, holeNumber.getText());
        pdt.setString(4, holeScore.getText());



        // put the rest of the code
        int n1 = pdt.executeUpdate();
        if (n1 > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserted into PlayerRound Successfully!");

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insert into PlayerRound failed!");
    }
```

Comment: Can you modify the table schema? You could (should) define playerID and holeNumber as foreign and primary keys. If you have foreign key support enabled, the database will determine if the foreign key constraints are fulfilled on each insertion and will give an error if not.

Comment: One way would be to trust the database - both the foreign key constraints, and a unique index you'll be defining on the `playerID` and `holeNumber` fields. If you try to insert something that doesn't fit the constraints, you'll get an sql exception which you can catch and work with.

Comment: @Jeremy @RealSkeptic They are all foreign keys except for the `holeScore`. The `playerID` will be used again for different holeNumbers e.g. playerID 1,2,3,4 etc will be going through holeNumber 1 to get to holeNumber 2 if you get what I mean. So I can't make `holeNumber` and `playerID` primary or unique

Comment: What you might try is to put a single composite unique index on the fields `(playerID, roundID, holeNumber)`. That would prevent a player revisiting a hole during a given round. (Or am I misunderstanding the meaning of "round?")

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Yes, that would be the problem. The same `playerID` won't be able to be inserted into `holeNumber` 2, 3, 4, etc

Comment: I don't play golf, so you'll have to spell this out for me. Can a player visit the same hole during *different* rounds, or is this what you're trying to prevent?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax That's another thing I didn't think about actually. But yes, the same player should be able to visit the same hole during a different round. The same player shouldn't be able to visit the same hole in the same round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_player_round_hole
  ON PlayerRound (playerID, roundID, holeNumber);
```

will tell the database to ensure that a given player can visit a given hole no more than once during a given round, but can visit multiple (different) holes in a given round and visit the same hole during different rounds. You can then simplify your query to

```
INSERT INTO PlayerRound (playerID, roundID, holeNumber, holeScore)
  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

JDBC will then throw a catchable exception if you try to violate this constraint, or the FK constraints linking to the other tables.

Comment: I just tested that out now. It works for not letting the same player be in the same hole on the same round but it doesn't let the player go to a different round.

Comment: There must be something else happening then. Can you post the complete `CREATE TABLE` statements for this and any related tables?

Comment: I added the "designer view" of the database at the top. The database is made in PHPMyAdmin and it has too much code to insert here. This is a link to my dropbox to see the exported database. [LINK HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zk33fehs3taa5vi/golfclub%20%284%29.sql?dl=0)

Comment: It works for me from the mysql command line. What error message do you get? (Yes, I did just create a copy of your database on my own system.)

Comment: So the first insert is `playerID=1 roundID=1 holeNumber=1` that works fine. Second insert is `playerID=1 roundID=1 holeNumber=2` thats works fine and then when i change the roundID ` `playerID=1 roundID=2 holeNumber=1` it fails and i get this error `Duplicate entry '1-1-1' for key 'ix_player_round_hole'`

Comment: In that case, I suspect the error is in your Java code. That's exactly the record I just inserted manually. Can you post the code you're using to do the insert?

Comment: That's just the SQL. I need to see the Java that *executes* the SQL, beginning with the call to `Connection.prepareStatement()` and ending with `PreparedStatement.execute()`. That's the code that's most likely causing the problem.

Comment: I added it to the bottom of the main question.

Comment: Hm. Then let's try simplifying the query: `INSERT INTO PlayerRound (playerID, roundID, holeNumber, holeScore) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)` You're on InnoDB tables, so the FK constraints will check themselves for you.

Comment: It still gives the same error. It must be something to do with the roundID.

Comment: Also, backtrack your `roundID` variable to where it's being modified, because the value in the error message is not the one you are intending to insert.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I will try figure this out myself and email one of my lecturers to help me. If i find out what the problem was. I will post it up here.

Comment: No problem. I've just added the simplified `INSERT` to my answer above, just to keep things complete.

Comment: I marked your answer correct since it did answer my question and is working. The error is on my side of things.

Comment: As we thought, the error was in the java code. I spent almost 3 hours looking at all my code and found out that my input box was inserting the entered playerID value into `playerID` AND `roundID` in the database. So there was no entry for `roundID` except that it was the same thing entered in `playerID`.